# Confirm before delete in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm currently editing a back-end page, but I have a few problems.
I need a confirmation before I delete the `Action` as you can see I tried this so far but my code is completely skipping the `confirm()` and only redirects to the index.

Please take a look at the controller code below

```
delete(req, res, next) {
        Action
                .findOne(req.param('id'))
                .then(({id}) => {
                    confirm('U staat op het punt een actie te verwijderen, klik op "ok" om hier mee door te gaan');
                    if(confirm()=== true) {
                        Action
                            .destroy(id)
                            .then(() => {
                                FlashService.setFlash(req, 'success', 'Action has been deleted')
                                res.redirect('/answer/index')
                            })
                            .catch(err => res.redirect('/answer/index'))
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => res.redirect('/answer/index'))
    }

}
```

I also tried `console.log` to see where my code is stranding but that would only give this error:

> Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: confirm is not defined

***edit***

I tought it also might be usefull to maybe see the HTML so here you go
as you can see the delete is called upon submit maybe I'm doing that extremly wrong but it seems to work besides the confirm mentioned before

```
<form action="/action/delete/<%= action.id %>" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    data-original-title="Verwijder"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

**EDIT 2.0**

I kind of fixed the problem but still not really I made the following javascript for the delete it's a little basic but that isn't the problem please take a look

```
<script>
    function Delete(){
        let c = confirm('U staat op het punt een actie te verwijderen, klik op "ok" om hier mee door te gaan');
        if (c){
            console.log("done");
            window.location.href = "/action/delete/<%= action.id %>"
        }

        else{
            console.log("failed")
            window.location.href = "/answer/show/<%= answer.id %>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

however, when I go to this page it says "action not defined" but I'm quite sure it is defined to be honest.

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be nice

Comment: You would like to confirm on the client side and not the server side :)

Comment: `if(confirm('U staat op het punt een actie te verwijderen, klik op "ok" om hier mee door te gaan')) {`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the client side `confirm` javascript on the server side. It does not exist. You should instead call confirm before sending request to the server.

Like so

```
<button onclick="delete()">Delete</button>

<script>
function delete() {
var confirm = confirm("Do you want to delete?")
if(confirm){
// Call server
}
}
</script>
```